# How to add expandable column to TableView in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I am quite new to Javafx. I searched a lot but I stuck in adding expandable rows( as shown in picture bellow) into my table. For example, I want to create file hierarchy using TableView. Can anybody help me with that? I appreciate any comment. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use ControlsFX and TableRowExpanderColumn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the so called TreeTableView for this if you need multiple columns: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/treetableview.html

Otherwise there is also the TreeView:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm